# Raise error if initiating a class, but not when initiating its subclasses

Tags: python

I'm implementing what I guess would be similar to an abstract class in Python. Here's an example:

```
In [12]: class A(object):
   ....:     def __init__(self, b):
   ....:         self.b = b
   ....:         raise RuntimeError('Cannot create instance of this class')
   ....:

In [13]: class B(A):
   ....:     pass
   ....:

In [14]: c=B(2)
```

What I want from this example, is to be able to initiate the B subclass, call `c.b` and retrieve 2. If I would call the A class, it would give me the RuntimeError. The problem with this implementation is that it will raise the error on B as well. How can I get around this?

One solution, as some commented, is to place the `self.b = b` part in the subclass and overwrite the `__init__` function. I would prefer to leave the code in the superclass if possible, since this will be duplicated quite in quite a few subclasses otherwise.

Thanks.

Comment: You should override `__init__` on B.  If you don't *need* to override `__init__` on B, then don't prohibit instantiating A.  In other words, you should only block instantiating the class if there is actual behavior that subclasses need to add, and in that case it doesn't make sense to instantiate a subclass that doesn't add that behavior.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yes, that's one solution, but I would very much like to have some code happening on the superclass before starting initiating the subclass. Should I put this in a separate function in the superclass which I call the first thing in the subclass initiation?

Comment: Note that python already has abstract classes, see the [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) module. However, your `A` class is **not** abstract in any reasonable sense. It has a single method that *does* contain a default implementation. If you want `A` to be abstract the whole body of `__init__` should be `raise RuntimeError(...)`.

Comment: @JimmyC: You could do that, or just say in the documentation that subclasses should call the superclass `__init__` (using `super`) before doing their own thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
import abc

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, b):
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

c = A(2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I edited the original post to clarify that I would prefer the self.b = b line to remain in the superclass.

Comment: You could make `B` your base concrete class, and subclass it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
        if type(self) == A:
            raise NotImplementedError('Cannot create instance of this class')

class B(A):
    pass

B(2) # doesn't raise
A(2) # raises
```